# Is it possible to load .load() function using jquery for windows phone in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, windows-phone-7, cordova

Please give any sample example for load function using jquery for windows phone in phonegap.

Can we use

```
("#home").load("new.html");

In windows phone. I tried like this but it is not working. Please suggest me any solution for this....
```

Answer (score 1):

check if load function is working or not 
like

```
$("#home").load("new.html", function(){
    alert("Done!");
});
```

Comment: Yeah it is showing "Done!" but the new.html page content is not showing

Comment: then check new.html is in right place or not.. is it working for other browsers?